# LINQ Query using Group By

Tags: c#, linq

I have a different answers associated with particulary QuestionID.I have to group the answers of each question.

```
Question  Table
----------
QuestionID
QuizID
QuestionText
IsMultipleAnswers

Answer Table
--------
AnswerID
QuestionID
AnswerText
IsCorrectAnswer
```

```
var query = from qst in context.Questions
            join ans in context.Answers
            on qst.QuestionID equals ans.QuestionID
```

What is the way to extend my query to group the answers associated with each questionID ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the group by operator:

```
var query = from qst in context.Questions
            join ans in context.Answers
            on qst.QuestionID equals ans.QuestionID
            group ans by ans.QuestionID into groups
            select groups;
```

Answer (score 3):

The [101 LINQ samples page for `GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336754.aspx#simple1) might help.